# Screen Reader not reading content of DataGrid from WPF Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, accessibility

I'm writing a BHO that uses an ElementHost to host a WPF User Control. Within the user control, I have a DataGrid that binds to an Observable Collection. Everything functions fine, except that the content is not being read by screen readers (I'm using NVDA to test, but QA is using JAWS).

I'm restricted from copy & pasting code on a public forum, but I can describe the layout that I'm creating. There are two datagrid. One contains all of the items from the Observable Collection and the other is a subset of the items. Each datagrid is in a separate Tab Item of a TabControl. As I stated, there is an ObservableCollection that holds my business objects. Each object binds to a row in the datagrid. Several of the columns require that I display multiple properties from the business object, so I'm using the DataGridTemplateColumn. Within the CellStyle, I have 3 DataTemplates set up; one for edit, one for add and one for view. The view DataTemplate is exactly the same as the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate.

One of the columns holds my action buttons. One of the buttons is an edit button which simply applies the edit template to the rows cells. Outside of the datagrid, I have a button that will add a new default item to the ObservableCollection, call UpdateLayout on the datagrid, then set the DataTemplate of the new item to the add template.

There is also a button that will grab information from a remote server, convert it to business objects and add them to the Observable Collection. The datagrid loads the new information with no problems.

When I use the function to pull the objects from the database, none of the information will be read by the screen reader. If I click the edit button, everything is read as expected. After returning to the "view" DataTemplate, everything reads as expected. If I use the Add button, everything reads as expected.

To make this more complicated, if I edit an item in one tab page and get it to be read, then go to the other tab page and come back, it's no longer reading.

I have a feeling that it's related to the how binding and templates interact, but I don't know enough about either to figure out a direction to go in resolving this.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: While I was creating the dummy project to show the issue, I discovered that the problem is not just limited to Template Columns. I created a business object with string properties, created an ObservableCollection with 10 objects in it and bound each property to a DataGridTextColumn, and it only reads the grid name and column index...the contents are never read.

Comment: The screen readers will read the generated HTML so can you post the HTML?

Comment: make a dummy project from scratch just to show some xaml and code here please.

Comment: This is inside of an IE add-in, using an element host. As far as I know, there's no HTML to view.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I created a REAL simple datagrid and it was reading without a problem, so I need to recreate more of what we're doing. I'll post it as soon as possible.

Comment: I created a dummy project and uploaded it to my skydrive here (https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=2841B241667F88DA!61355&authkey=!AKv0ZkTSvd86v1Q&ithint=file%2c.zip)